# In Node.js server, is there a performance penalty in creating multiple Axios clients via axios.create() vs a singleton style of adapter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, axios

Does spawning multiple Axios clients using `axios.create` incur performance penalties or other considerations? Example: For 5000 simultaneous requests to SomeApiClient, is there any difference between the following approaches:

**Approach A**

```
function callSomeApi = async () => { 
  const client = axios.create(...); 
  await client.post(...); 
};

// For 5000 simultaneous requests
await callSomeApi();
```

**Approach B**

```
class SomeApiClient {
  constructor() { this.client = axios.create(...); }
  async callSomeApi() { await this.client.post(...); }; 
}
const apiClient = new SomeApiClient();

// For 5000 simultaneous requests
await apiClient.callSomeApi();
```

Comment: `calling axios.create 5000 times` vs `calling axios.create in constructor 1 time and calling post request 5000 times`. so 1 synchronous step happening 5000 times and blocking main thread in approach A

Comment: try to run Your code in debug mode and attach to it from browser and see how many times what method called and etc.

Comment: also You can dump the heap and analyze it also: https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/04/03/how-to-track-and-fix-memory-leak-with-nodejs.html

Comment: @num8er I've edited the sample with the proper async/await calls to avoid blocking the main thread.

Comment: then it adds extra work to garbage collector to cleanup memory allocated for 5000 client variable in first example.